# convert interval year to month to "mm/yy" format

Tags: sql, database, intervals

Hello  I need a little help. I need to convert interval year to month to mm/yy format. Example: '1 year and 6 months'.
This is my code, I am new to sql and I'm not very familiar with it

```
*SELECT DECODE(pd.LANGUAGE_ID, 'US', pd.TRANSLATED_NAME)PRODUCT_NAME_US,
       DECODE(pd.LANGUAGE_ID, 'US', SUBSTR(pd.TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...') PRODUCT_DESC_NAME,
       DECODE(pd.LANGUAGE_ID, 'RU', pd.TRANSLATED_NAME)PRODUCT_NAME_RU,
       DECODE(pd.LANGUAGE_ID, 'RU', SUBSTR(pd.TRANSLATED_DESCRIPTION, 1, 30), '...')PRODUCT_DES_RU,
       pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD AS Warranty, inv.QUANTITY_ON_HAND AS IN_STOCK
FROM PRODUCT_DESCRIPTIONS pd JOIN PRODUCT_INFORMATION pin
ON pd.PRODUCT_ID = pin.PRODUCT_ID
JOIN INVENTORIES inv
ON pd.PRODUCT_ID = inv.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE pd.TRANSLATED_NAME LIKE '%Monitor%'
AND pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD IN (SELECT CASE WHEN WARRANTY_PERIOD IN '0' THEN 'No Warranty'
                                        WHEN TO_NUMBER(WARRANTY_PERIOD) > 0 THEN 'fmYYYY "years and" Month'
                                        WHEN WARRANTY_PERIOD = 'YYYY' THEN 'fmYYYY "years"'
                                        WHEN TO_NUMBER(WARRANTY_PERIOD) < 12 THEN 'fmMonth'
                                        ELSE 'WARRANTY_PERIOD'
                                   END WARRANTY
                            FROM PRODUCT_INFORMATION)
AND inv.QUANTITY_ON_HAND < 1000
ORDER BY pin.WARRANTY_PERIOD DESC, pin.PRODUCT_NAME ASC;*
```

The first checks if its 0 then 'No warranty'. The second it it's > 0 then ' years and '. The third if the number of months = number of years then ' years'. The last one: it  < 12 then ' months'.

And I need to show the product name in English (US) and Russian (RU) and if the description is longer than 30 characters I need to substract it to 30 characters long and add '...' in the end.

Comment: Could you provide some test data? What are the values of the columns you're working with and whats your desired result?

Comment: The WARRANTY_PERIOD column is like this: 
+00-03

+00-03

+00-06

+00-06

And the result should be: '1 year and 6 months' if the period is > 0 (for example)

Comment: WARRANTY_PERIOD  is saved in which format?

Comment: it is saved in INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH

Comment: What platform?  MsSQL, MySql, Postgres, Oracle?

Comment: Oracle. I'm trying with EXCTRACT but it wants data and I have to compare it to number